# Paypal Buy Now button - Need to track user/client ID payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment

I've set up a PayPal Buy Now button. The wizard was awesome and easy but how do I keep track of whether my user has paid or not from my website? Each user has a unique user ID. On PayPal payment success, is there a way to redirect back to my site with the user ID in the query string? Or is there a more secure way or checking?

Answer (score 0):

There is a official PayPal SDK based on REST APIs on GitHub (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) which covers this functionality.
It is very easy to use and integrate. Just take a look into the samples.